# google functions fails on deploy with no reason using typescript

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

During deployment, Cloud Functions fails with no error code.

The typescript compiler doesn't give any errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check your enums.
this line will fail
`export enum ManagerStatus {`

this is not:
`export const enum ManagerStatus {`